# Is the "triangle inequality for reciprocals" a sufficient condition for altitudes of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, geometric-inequalities, triangle-inequality

In connection with a [question asked in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57468275#57468275), I thought about this:

**Question:** What are sufficient and necessary conditions for three numbers $h_a$, $h_b$, $h_c$ to be heights of a triangle?

I learned from the Wikipedia article "[List of triangle inequalities § Altitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities#Altitudes)" ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_triangle_inequalities&oldid=996185661#Altitudes)) that:

> The reciprocals of the altitudes of any triangle can themselves form a triangle:
> $$\frac{1}{h_a}<\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}, \quad \frac{1}{h_b}<\frac{1}{h_c}+\frac{1}{h_a},  \quad \frac{1}{h_c}<\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}.$$

Wikpedia gives as a reference: Mitchell, Douglas W., "[A Heron-type formula for the reciprocal area of a triangle](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025557200178532)", ''Mathematical Gazette'' 89 (November 2005), 494.

**Question:** The above three inequalities giva a necessary condition - are they also a sufficient condition? (I.e., if we're given $h_a$, $h_b$, $h_c$ that fulfill these three inequalities, is there a triangle with altitudes of those lengths?)

I guess the answer is yes. For example if I look at the result from the blog post called [Altitude Reciprocals](http://lostmathlessons.blogspot.com/2017/12/altitude-reciprocals.html) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20210328094824/http://lostmathlessons.blogspot.com/2017/12/altitude-reciprocals.html)) in The Lost Math Lessons blog (by David Vreken), I read that:

> The reciprocals of the altitudes of any triangle can themselves form a triangle that is similar to the original triangle.

So it seems that it would be enough to take the triangle with the sides $\frac1{h_a}$, $\frac1{h_b}$, $\frac1{h_c}$ and then to scale it correctly. But maybe there are some other, more straightforward ways to see this.

---

This seems a very natural question, so I expected to find something about this on Mathematics Stack Exchange. But I did not succeed. (It is certainly possible that the same question has been asked before, but I failed to find a duplicate.)

Comment: We have equalities $h_a=2S/a$, $h_b=2S/b$, $h_c=2S/c$, where $S$ is the area of the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Basically, you need to construct the trangle with those lengths and to perform some homothety.

Comment: And to find the coefficient it's sufficient to express $S$ in terms of $h_a,h_b,h_c$. This can be done via Heron's formula (as the title of the mentioned reference suggests)/ Namely, use $16S^2=(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b+c)$ and then replace $a$ with $2S/h_a$ etc.

Comment: @richrow I guess you could actually convert your comments to an answer.